# Flipped \cong symbol

Tags: math-mode

I am looking for a mathematical symbol that I have seen in some papers. It looks very similar to the `\cong` symbol, but is flipped vertically. In other words, what I am looking for is an equal sign underlined by a tilde. I have seen `\eqsim`, but this is not what I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a
greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange
at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of
our trying to keep everything very concise.
[Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)
is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you. [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Comment: And it's not just a flipped `\cong`?

Comment: @jonalv It is exactly a vertically flipped \cong, but I'm not sure how to flip it. Is there an easy way to do this? The symbol doesn't exist on it's own in latex or any of the packages I could find (I've been through the full symbol list and used detexify with no success)

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\congx{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\cong$}\begin{document}$A\congx B$\end{document}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand*{\mycong}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{.25ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\cong$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \mycong B_{A \mycong B_{A \mycong B}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `\mycong` doesn't look centered vertically on the math axis -- it looks too high.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the tilde should probably be set in such a way that the `=` sign is not moved with respect to its normal position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@ndereq}[2]{%
  \vtop{
    \lineskiplimit\maxdimen
    \lineskip-.5\p@
    \ialign{$\m@th#1\hfil##\hfil$\crcr=\crcr#2\crcr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\fcong}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@ndereq\sim\relax}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
$A=B\fcong C_{\fcong=}$
\end{document}
```

[image]